# Python collect System Stats

Tags: python, statistics

I am trying to collect system stats using python. Mostly looking for a libery or github project that does this already. I am looking to be able to collect/log the following things.

- CPU Usage and or Load average
- Disk Free space
- Disk IO thoughput
- Ram usage (Free, Active, Cached)
- Network IO
- Bandwidth Usaged
- Uptime
- Anything else useful in server monitoring.

Edit:
I am mostly looking for support in Linux systems I will move on to windows systems later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the psutil module [here](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/), take a look at the example shown. However, for `DISK IO` you might have to use the `wmi` and the `pywin32` modules.

For example, for `DISK QUEUE LENGTH` with windows use this:

```
from win32pdh import *
import time

while True:
    path = MakeCounterPath((None,"PhysicalDisk","_Total",None,0,"Avg. Disk Queue Length"),0)
    query_handle = OpenQuery()
    counter_handle = AddCounter(query_handle, path)
    query_handle = OpenQuery()
    counter_handle = AddCounter(query_handle, path)
    CollectQueryData(query_handle)
    time.sleep(2)
    CollectQueryData(query_handle)
    (counter_type, value) = GetFormattedCounterValue(counter_handle, PDH_FMT_DOUBLE)
    print value
    CloseQuery(query_handle)
```

It uses the counters of the perfmon app on windows. For linux, there are multiple tools for DISK IO.

For linux `DISK IO` check out `iotop` [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/hardware/linux-iotop-simple-top-like-io-monitor/attachment/iotop-output-screenshot/)

Also, example of Linux diskstats use this, it periodically parses `/proc/diskstats`

```
def diskstats_parse(dev=None):
    file_path = '/proc/diskstats'
    result = {}

    # ref: http://lxr.osuosl.org/source/Documentation/iostats.txt
    columns_disk = ['m', 'mm', 'dev', 'reads', 'rd_mrg', 'rd_sectors',
                    'ms_reading', 'writes', 'wr_mrg', 'wr_sectors',
                    'ms_writing', 'cur_ios', 'ms_doing_io', 'ms_weighted']

    columns_partition = ['m', 'mm', 'dev', 'reads', 'rd_sectors', 'writes', 'wr_sectors']

    lines = open(file_path, 'r').readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if line == '': continue
        split = line.split()
        if len(split) == len(columns_disk):
            columns = columns_disk
        elif len(split) == len(columns_partition):
            columns = columns_partition
        else:
            # No match
            continue

        data = dict(zip(columns_disk, split))
        if dev != None and dev != data['dev']:
            continue
        for key in data:
            if key != 'dev':
                data[key] = int(data[key])
        result[data['dev']] = data

    return result
```

I hope this helps. :)

Comment: Do these all have linux support.

Comment: psutil is i believe majority linux, but `wmi` and `pywin32` are for windows.